# Как в php избавится от конструкции if isset()?

Tags: php, php5

Чем можно заменить данную конструкцию?

В коде очень много подобных проверок, а выносить в отдельную функцию не очень хочется и данный массив берется после обработки xml файла.

```
if(isset($dict_notification->{'purchaseDocumentation'}->{'grantStartDate'})) {
    $date = $dict_notification->{'purchaseDocumentation'}->{'grantStartDate'};
} else {
    return; // old - $date = null;
}
```

Comment: Начиная с версии 5.3 можно писать `$date = $dict_notification->{'purchaseDocumentation'}->{'grantStartDate'} ?: null;` Правда если у вас в переменной будет `false`, `0`, `'0'` и т.п., то в `$date` вернет `NULL` :(

Comment: @Visman, `false`, `0` and `'0'` - вполне корректные и, возможно, одни из ожидаемых вариантов. Лучше в самом начале, после парсинга, одним скопом (массивы ожидаемых ключей, возможные маркеры и т. п.) проверить.

Comment: @Visman да, данный вариант подходит, а возможно сделать выход из процедуры? 
Как пример: 
`$id=$dict_notification->{'id'} ?: return;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

либо вынести в отдельную функцию, массив по ссылке передавайте в нее - ничего страшного. Что-то в духе:

```
function turboset(&$array, $key, $default=''){
        if (!isset($array[$key])){ return $default; }
        return $array[$key];
    }
```

либо PHP7, пример [оттуда](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

Comment: php v 5.6, и не очень хотело бы использовать функцию

Comment: другого реального выхода нет, имхо, впрочем, буду следить за развитием событий